# does amazon sns provide support for ios push notifications using GCM?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I know Amazon Sns can send notifications to Android using GCM(Getting Started with Google Cloud Messaging for Android).
Can I send IOS notifications using Amazon Sns & GCM or I should use APNs for sending IOS notifications?

Comment: If the question is, can you use GCM with iOS, then the answer is yes. However, GCM is being replaced by FCM (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  If yes,why do they have "Getting Started with Google Cloud Messaging for Android" & "Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) for both iOS and Mac OS X"?

Comment: Good question. Perhaps because GCM is the native option for Android, and not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it supports Apple APNS.

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html
```

[Getting Started with Apple Push Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html)